# How to filter on pivot fields in laravel

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have 3 tables, **users**, **orders** and **statuses**. Pivot table **order_status** has extra columns: **user_id** and **created_at** (to get which user and when set that status). **Order** model has method:

```
// get latest status for order, and tie user (user_id in pivot table)    
public function latestStatus(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Status')
                ->select(array('*','User.name'))
                ->orderBy('order_status.created_at','desc')
                ->join('users','order_status.user_id','=','users.id')
                ->withTimestamps();
                ->limit(1,0);
        }
```

so if i call:

```
$orders = Orders::with('latestStatus')->get();
```

i can have orders with latest status. that's ok.

i need to have some filtering, both on order properties and by latest status, for example: (table **orders** has columns **location**, **buyer**) - how to pull all orders with:

```
order.location_id = in ("ny", "nm")
order.buyer_id = in ("1", "3")
order_status.user_id = in ("1", "5")
order_status.created_at = between (2015-10-04, 2015-10-06)
order_status.status_id = in ("2", "8", "9")
```

Calling "where" on Orders just solves location and buyer part...

```
$orders = Orders::whereIn('location_id',["ny", "nm"])
         ->whereIn('buyer_id',["1","3"])
         ->with('latestStatus')
         ->get();
```

so question is how to filter on pivot fields (find orders with specific statuses created between specific dates)?

tnx
Y

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's how i did it:

```
$orders = Order::with('lateststatus')
    ->whereHas('lateststatus', function ($q) use ($dateTo, $dateFrom, $statuses) {
                                $q->where('order_status.created_at','>=',$dateFrom);
                                $q->where('order_status.created_at','<',$dateTo);
                                $q->whereIn('order_status.status_id',$statusi); 
                            }
            );
$orders = $orders->whereIn('location_id',$locations); }
$orders = $orders->whereIn('user_id',$users); }
$orders = $orders->->get();
```

PS: i altered db structure, so now i'm keeping user_id in orders table.